# Display template not called if TypeConverter exists

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, html-helper

As soon as I register a TypeConverter for a complex type, it fails to load the correct (base type) display template for properties of a derived type, i.e., `@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.My_Derived_ComplexTypeProp)` fails to load the `MyComplexType` display template.

I've debugged the display template selection logic a little bit, and the problem seems to be very obvious:

```
// From TemplateHelpers:
internal static IEnumerable<string> GetViewNames(ModelMetadata metadata, params string[] templateHints)
{
  [...]
  yield return fieldType.Name; // TRY 1: Type, but no base type walking

  if (!(fieldType == typeof (string))) // YEP ...
  {
    if (!metadata.IsComplexType) // Unfortunately YEP (see below...)
    {
      if (fieldType.IsEnum) // NOPE
        yield return "Enum";
      else if (fieldType == typeof (DateTimeOffset)) // NOPE
        yield return "DateTime";
      yield return "String"; // TRY 2: string => uh oh, string will be found, and we do not use the correct display template.
    }
    [...]
    else
    {
       [...] // only in here we would have the base type walk
    }
    [...]

// From ModelMetadata:
public virtual bool IsComplexType
{
  get
  {
    // !!! !!! WTF !!! !!!:
    // Why is IsComplexType returning false if we cannot convert from string?
    return !TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(this.ModelType).CanConvertFrom(typeof (string));
  }
}
```

As soon as the logic detects "no complex type" it simply checks for enumerations, DateTimes and returns the template for `string` otherwise! But look at the implementation of `IsComplexType` -> if convertible to `string` it is treated like a simple type!

So, of course, as soon as you register a type converter for a complex type, the display template resolution fails to use the correct template.

Is there a known workaround? I cannot believe, I'm one of the few people running into this until now...

I have found [Cannot use TypeConverter and custom display/editor template together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9297565/cannot-use-typeconverter-and-custom-display-editor-template-together), however, the "solution" which is marked as answer, is not really a solution. It just hackarounds the problem...

Comment: If anyone is interested, I created a report at https://forums.asp.net/t/2107050.aspx